# Remove duplicate objects from arraylist and consolidate data with unique object

Tags: java

Please help me to resolve the below task and let me know if you have any questions.

I have data in the departmentList object. There are 3 department objects in the departmentList. Object 1 has 2 employee records. Object 3 is separate dept object but with same deptid.

(Deptobject DEPTID DEPTNAME Location EmpId EmpName Empsal)

1           1       ABC      NY       1     David   $5000

1           1       ABC      NY       2     Sam     $6000

2           2       PQR      NC       4     Brian   $5500

**3**           1       ABC      NY       5     Glen    $7000

I need to consolidate the data into one object (under unique deptid).

Expected Out put from above sample data:-
(departmentList contains 2 objects and object1 (depid:1) should contains 3 employee object under 1 employeelist object )

(Deptobject DEPTID DEPTNAME Location EmpId EmpName Empsal)

1           1       ABC      NY       1     David   $5000

1           1       ABC      NY       2     Sam     $6000

2           2       PQR      NC       4     Brian   $5500

**1**           1       ABC      NY       5     Glen    $7000

```
List<Department> departmentsList = new ArrayList<Department>(); 

public Department
 {
  int deptId;
  String deptName;
  String deptLocation;
  List<Employee> employeeList=new ArrayList<Employee>();

 getterxxx();
 setters();
private void addEmployee(Employee e)
{
 this.employeeList.add(e);
 }
```

}

```
 public class  Employee
 {
  int empId;
  String empName;
  int sal;
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you mean here, could you explain yourself better please?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you don't want to have two instances of the same object you could use a Set<Employee>, but I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically, We're getting big ArrayList object from another system / module. So, we can't change the code of the other system / module. That given (source)arraylist has multiple department arraylists. The multiple department arraylists could have same departmentId. Each department arraylist has multiple employee arraylists. So, we need to process that big arraylist by removing the duplicate department arraylists and before removing duplicate department arraylists move their employee arraylist objects to one department object (basedon deptId).So the final list should contain unique deptid objs

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved.

```
    //Source arrayList
    ArrayList<Department> originalDepartmentsList=externalSys.getDepartmentsList();

    //for duplicate Department
    ArrayList<Department> duplicateDeptList = new ArrayList<Department>();

    //for unique Department
    HashMap<String,Department> uniqueDepts = new HashMap<String,Department>();

    //For duplicate identification and create a seperate list purpose
    Set<String> deptIdsList = new HashSet<String>();    

    Iterator originalIte=originalDepartmentsList.iterator();
    System.out.println("size of Department objs count in originalDepartmentsList.."+originalDepartmentsList.size());

    while(originalIte.hasNext())
    {
        Department deptObj=(Department) originalIte.next();
        String deptId=deptObj.getDeptId();
        if(!deptIdsList.add(deptId))
        {
            duplicateDeptList.add(deptObj);
            System.out.println("Duplicate SId is."+deptId);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("deptId "+deptId+" is added to the uniques map.");
            uniqueDepts.put(deptId,deptObj);
        }       

    }

    System.out.println("duplicateDeptList size."+duplicateDeptList.size());
    System.out.println("uniqueDepts size."+uniqueDepts.size());
    System.out.println("********************************");

    //Adding Employee objects to the unique Department list.
    Iterator dupListIte=duplicateDeptList.iterator();
    while(dupListIte.hasNext())
    {
        Department deptObj=(Department) dupListIte.next();
        String deptId=deptObj.getDeptId();
        System.out.println("Duplicate DeptId."+deptId);

        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList= deptObj.getEmployeeList();

       if(employeeList!=null && employeeList.size()>0){

         Iterator empIte=employeeList.iterator();
        while(empIte.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("Employee list size before: for DeptId "+deptId+" .."+uniqueDepts.get(deptId).getEmployeeList().size());
            Employee empObj=(Employee) empIte.next();
            uniqueDepts.get(deptId).addToEmployeeList(empObj);
            System.out.println("Employee list size after: for DeptId "+deptId+" .."+uniqueDepts.get(deptId).getEmployeeList().size());
        }
}
```

}
List finalDeptList=new ArrayList(uniqueDepts.values());